# Почему 3 сайта хэшкода - это плохо?

Tags: обсуждение, тематика

> На ХэшКоде не было особо разговоров за жизнь и у нас было три сайта: для программистов, для администраторов и пользователей. И это была большая ошибка.

Почему наличие трёх сайтов было ошибкой?

PS: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25299470#25299470.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Дублирование вопросов

За идею разделения сообществ по большому счету выступают знатоки, но вопросы задают те, кто что-то изучает. Их интерес лежит в плоскости получения ответа, причем как можно быстрее. В результате, они либо дублируют вопрос на всех сайтах, либо задают его в более крупном сообществе, а не более подходящем, игнорирую тематику. В этом случае, идея разделения на разные сообщества для классификации знаний теряет смысл.

#### Публикация вопросов не на том сайте

Даже если участник хочет разместить вопрос на верном сайте, ему необходимо внимательно прочитать правила, понять их и принять правильное решение. Уверен, что даже у самых опытных участников всех сообществ (программисты, пользователи, системные администраторы) иногда возникает вопрос о правильности сайта при публикации вопросов, например, про конфигурирование веб-сервера для Ubuntu.

#### Размер сообщества

Чем уже тематика, тем меньше знатоков, которые могут поделиться альтернативным подходом к решению задачи. К примеру, разработчики ПО для встроенных систем не будут называть себя системными администраторами, но знания для ответов на вопросы про Linux у них точно есть.

---

Расширяя тематику сообщества мы получим порядка 10% около-тематических вопросов, которых можно никогда не видеть за счет добавления игнорируемых меток. Более того, если вопросы не получают внимания сообщества (то есть ответов) или такие вопросы будут удалены сборщиком мусора, достаточно проголосовать против. Учитывая это и ответы [@Nick Volynkin](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1736/6) и [@PashaPash](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1735/6), на мой взгляд, намного эффективней иметь одно сообщество с расширенной тематикой.

Answer (score 10):

- На английском Stack Overflow - 7900 вопросов в день
- На английском Super User (для продвинутых пользователей) - 187 вопросов в день
- На английском Server Fault (для админов) - 106 вопросов в день

Если предположить, что соотношение разработчиков/пользователей/админов в русскоязычном сегменте то же самое, то три раздельных сайта дают

- 110 вопросов в день на ru.SO (это текущий показатель)
- 2 вопроса в день на ru.SU
- 1 вопрос в день на ru.SF

нет смысла держать отдельный сайт ради двух вопросов в день.

Answer (score 4):

В дополнение:

- потому что о разделении англоязычных сайтов уже не раз пожалели;
- потому что некоторые темы оказываются разорванными между двумя или тремя сайтами (VCS, весь DevOps, базы данных,  ОС (особенно *nix) и многое другое);
- потому что разделение, на мой взгляд, довольно искусственное;
- и потому что сделать три хороших сайта и сформировать три сообщества примерно втрое сложнее.

---

И тут есть такой сложный момент. Я одновременно понимаю, что нет другого хорошего сайта, где можно было бы задавать пользовательские вопросы про Windows и офисные приложения. Но при этом не хочу чтобы Ru.SO был известен как сайт, где нужно задавать такие вопросы. Это потому, что набегут школьники и будут спрашивать, почему игры не запускаются. А если выделить такой сайт, то почти наверняка специалисты туда не пойдут. И там будет помесь ответов@мру с кухонным прибором.