# Как устроено сообщество "stack overflow на русском"?

Tags: поддержка, stackoverflow, stackexchange

Всем привет!
Объясните пожалуйста структуру сообщества stack overflow на русском.

До этого заходил в англоязычные сообщества, разделенные по темам. Я правильно понимаю что это сообщество общее для самых разных тем на русском языке, и вместо разделения на темы-сообщества здесь теги?

Или это сообщество посвящено исключительно программированию? В таком случае есть ли еще другие русскоязычные сообщества?

Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Релевантно: [Почему 3 сайта хэшкода - это плохо?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1734)

Comment: И ещё: [Как создать русскоязычный сайт на StackExchange?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1253)

Comment: И это: [Где задавать не IT-шные вопросы на движке StackExchange?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/708)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stack Overflow на русском – это профессиональное сообщество. На сайте обсуждаются вопросы касающиеся, в основном, программирования. В силу идеологии проекта, в которой сообщество, то есть реальные люди, управляют как самим сообществом, так и содержимым сайта, тематика сайта может быть (и была) расширена. [На сайте можно задать вопрос по](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

- к конкретной задаче программирования - коду, алгоритмам, реализации алгоритмов на определенных языках программирования;
- к инструментам для разработки - языки программирования, среды, операционные системы, пакеты программ, фреймворки, библиотеки;
- к проектированию, использованию и администрированию баз данных;
- к настройке физических, виртуальных серверов, серверов-приложений, серверов баз данных, веб-серверов, файл-серверов, средствам их настройки, - мониторинга и этих автоматизации процессов;
- к реальной проблеме, встречающейся на практике, решение которой можно изложить кратко в паре абзацев, и которая уникальна для разработки программного обеспечения и профессионального администрирования IT систем.

Повторюсь, Stack Overflow – это в первую очередь люди, которые своим добродетелем помогают коллегам знаниями. Это означает, что правила сообщества зависят от его участников и могут меняться со временем.

Сейчас на Stack Overflow на русском *частично* допустимы вопросы, которые в англоязычном сообществе были бы перенесены на под-сообщества [Super User](https://superuser.com/) или [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/). Это происходит потому что:

- На данный момент, мы (и компания, и сообщество) не в состоянии поддерживать несколько сайтов.
- Наши англоязычные коллеги не раз выражали мнение, что решение о разделение было ошибочным. [Это вопрос поднимался и в сообществе на русском языке](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1734/).
- Допустимы только те вопросы тематики SF и SU, которые с большой вероятностью получат ответ и будут интересны сообществу.

Дополню ответ цитатой комментария [к ответу](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1861/6) [@Suvitruf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/15479/).

> Утверждение, что «ru Stack Overflow это место для около IT-шных вопросов» – не верно. Stack Overflow на русском – это в первую очередь профессиональный ресурс, где ищут решения на ежедневные прикладные *рабочие* вопросы. Ничего около «IT-шного» или не относящегося к работе на сайте нет, и быть не должно. Пограничные ситуации возникают в контексте отдельных тематик, так как мы, как истинные энтузиасты своего дела, не можем ограничиться просто, к примеру, Java или программированием. Естественная тяга к знаниям порождает необходимость в вопросах, например, про ОС, но эти вопросы также профессиональны, как и остальные.

При желании, в любой момент вы можете поднять вопрос на Мете о необходимости добавления или удаления какой-либо категории вопросов из списка разрешенных тематик.

Answer (score 12):

Согласно [правилам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), Stack Overflow на русском — это место для около IT-шных вопросов: программирование, разработка, проектирование, администрирование - всё сюда. В силу того, что у нас русскоязычная аудитория маленькая, делать множество ресурсов по различным тематикам не имеет смысла, ибо там будет полтора человека сидеть.

С одной стороны, ru SO обхватывает очень много тематик вместе, с другой...однозначности нет. Посему, казалось бы, нормальный вопрос может быть закрыт как офтопик.

Точно так же нет и однозначности в плане вопросов-обсуждений. На en SO, как правило, вопросы подразумевающие различные трактовки, opinion based ответы закрываются.

Я не первый год сижу на SO, как и в своё время много сидел на hashcode, но сам порой не совсем уверен в тематике ресурса. Да, с явными вопросами по разработке и т.п. проблем не возникает, но из-за всеобъемлющей тематики ресурса слишком много пограничных ситуаций возникает.

На мете часто обсуждения возникают вроде [этого](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%92-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8F%D1%85), но однозначной позиции людей я не наблюдаю.

Comment: Большое спасибо за подробное разъяснение! 

Да, я подумал что такой подход из-за аудитории, хотя мне кажется есть более-менее активные сообщества в некоторых других тематиках (которые просто общаются на других ресурсах и в  соцсетях)... большинство там наверное может пользоваться англоязычным SO, но возможно со временем новые разделы здесь смогут оправдать свое существоание...

Comment: Но вообще здорово что вы есть - ru SO! :)

Comment: Утверждение _«ru Stack Overflow это место для около IT-шных вопросов»_ – не верно. Stack Overflow на русском – это в первую очередь профессиональный ресурс, где ищут решения на рабочие вопросы. Ничего около «IT-шного» тут нет, и быть не должно. Если это не так, можете винить от части меня. Пограничные ситуации возникают в контексте отдельных тематик, так как мы, как истинные энтузиасты своего дела, не можем ограничиться просто Java, или программированием. Естественная тяга к знаниям порождает необходимость в вопросах, например, про ОС, но эти вопросы также профессиональны, как и остальные.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky " не верно. Stack Overflow на русском – это в первую очередь профессиональный ресурс" не вижу противоречий с моим ответом)

Comment: @Suvitruf Скорее всего, мы по-разному понимаем «около ИТ-шное». На мой взгляд, это а-ля статьи про жизнь программиста и как круто им быть. Такому содержимому, на мой взгляд, не место на Stack Overflow. Есть уйма более подходящих ресурсов. Кстати, в большинстве компаний, ИТ-шник – это админ/эникейщик, который к программированию не имеет никакого отношения, как минимум на работе.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky я имел именно практическую составляющую IT: разработка, проектирование, администрирование и т.п. )

Answer (score 5):

Добавлю к @Suvitruf:

В отличие от традиционной форумной системы, здесь все устроено проще и сложнее одновременно:

1. Вопросы/темы помечаются метками/тегами, по которым можно сортировать/фильтровать по мере надобности. В традиционной форумной системе невозможно задать вопрос одновременно по Java и C# - это будут 2 разные ветки форумов, а здесь пожалуйста. Достаточно поставить 2 метки [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) и [c#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) и ваш вопрос прочтут специалисты и по тем и по другим культурам;
2. Предусмотрена система оценок, вопросы/ответы с хорошими оценками будут находиться в топе и вызывать интерес, их будут читать, комментировать и проч. Вопросы с низкими оценками будут "тонуть" в пучине безвестности. Оценки может ставить любой участник - оценки ставятся анонимно.
3. Оценка вопроса/ответа добавляет рейтинг автора вопроса/ответа. Чем выше рейтинг, тем больше возможностей.

Comment: У автора репутация больше ста, значит он знает как устроен stackexchange

Comment: @Oceinic именно. Автор хотел узнать, чем ru SO отличается от других сайтов stack exchange )

Comment: @Barmaley Большое спасибо! Эта возможность коснуться сразу нескольких тематик в одном вопросе, с одной стороны наверное может вносить беспорядок, когда какая-то из тем задета совсем поверхностно, с другой должна быть очень удобна если речь идет о вопросах взаимодействия разных сфер... Спасибо!

Comment: По второму пункту не соглашусь - есть много вопросов, нужных людям (много просмотров), но без внимания сообщества (мало голосов). И тонут они в безвестности лишь пока на не реализуют вот эту фичу: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1837/